# SQL server - Group by Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

This is my sample data:

```
Autonumber   ProductSKU    Quantity
---------    ----------    --------
ABCD123      00001597      42
ABCD123      00001600      42
ABCD124      00001597      35
ABCD124      00001600      35
ABCD125      00001597      39
ABCD125      00001600      39
```

I have to derive the `Autonumber` column values based on the `Quantity` and `ProductSKU`. `Autonumber` should change when `Quantity` & `ProductSKU` changes. 
How can I achieve this? I have the logic to increment `Autonumber` but confused with the group by logic. kindly help me with this.

---

**EDIT (copied from OP's post in the answers section)**:

I have a logic that calculates Autonumber, which is incremented for each row.

**Query:**

```
IF @p_channelname ='ABCD'
    BEGIN
            ;WITH CTE_AUTONUMBER_ABCD_AMER AS
                    (SELECT RECORDSEQ
                            ,'ABCD'+CAST(@PrevOrderID+DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY (RECORDSEQ )) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS AUTONUMBER_UPDATE
                            , AUTONUMBER
                            , LINENUMBER
                , DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY (RECORDSEQ )) AS LINENUMBER_UPDATE
                    FROM TABLE1 TGT
                    WHERE TGT.[INTERFACE NAME] =@p_interface
                                        AND TGT.[FILENAME]= @p_sourcefilename
                                            AND TGT.CHANNEL = @p_channelname
                                            AND  TGT.GEO='America' 
                    ) UPDATE CTE_AUTONUMBER_ABCD_AMER 
                            SET AUTONUMBER = AUTONUMBER_UPDATE,
                LINENUMBER=LINENUMBER_UPDATE
```

Currently Autonumber values is :

```
Autonumber   ProductSKU    Quantity
---------    ----------    --------
ABCD123      00001597      42
ABCD124      00001600      42
ABCD125      00001597      35
ABCD126      00001600      35
ABCD127      00001597      39
ABCD128      00001600      39
```

I want the Autonumber values to be generated as:

```
Autonumber   ProductSKU    Quantity
---------    ----------    --------
ABCD123      00001597      42
ABCD123      00001600      42
ABCD124      00001597      35
ABCD124      00001600      35
ABCD125      00001597      39
ABCD125      00001600      39
```

This is the current query:
;WITH CTE_AUTONUMBER_EPIC_AMER AS
            (SELECT RECORDSEQ
                    ,CASE WHEN @P_CHANNELNAME ='Epic' 
                                THEN  'Epic'+CAST(CAST(AUTONUMBER AS INT) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                                END   AS AUTONUMBER_UPDATE
                    , AUTONUMBER
                    , LINENUMBER
                    , DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY (RECORDSEQ )) AS LINENUMBER_UPDATE
            FROM IC_CTXS_TRANSACTION_SOURCEFEED TGT
            WHERE TGT.[INTERFACE NAME] =@p_interface
                                AND TGT.[FILENAME]= @p_sourcefilename
                                AND TGT.CHANNEL = @p_channelname
                                        AND  TGT.GEO ='America'
                                        AND ISNUMERIC(CAST(AUTONUMBER AS INT))=1
                                        AND AUTONUMBER  IS NOT NULL
            ) UPDATE CTE_AUTONUMBER_EPIC_AMER 
                    SET AUTONUMBER = AUTONUMBER_UPDATE,
                    LINENUMBER = LINENUMBER_UPDATE

How can I include the logic in this without disturbing the structure of the query?

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  You need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows.

Comment: And besides the order issue, I don't understand your logic. Based on your data, wouldn't the `autonumber` value increment for every row since every row has a different `ProductSKU/Quantity` value from the previous row?  Consider posting the SQL you have constructed so far.

Comment: That has nothing of 'auto' and little of 'number'. You need to show your code, and clarify your expecte result.,

Comment: Please provide more background for this task, what `Autonumber` should represent and how is it intended to be used?

Comment: I have updated the question with the query and required format. Do help out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a new query, with the logic you want, but it seems pretty crazy for me:

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE1 FROM (VALUES
(00001597,42,1),(00001600,42,2),(00001597,35,3),(00001600,35,4),(00001597,39,5),
(00001600,39,6)) as x(ProductSKU, Quantity, RECORDSEQ);
GO
;WITH Change as (
SELECT t1.*, 
    CASE WHEN IsNull(t1.ProductSKU,-1) != IsNull(t2.ProductSKU,-1) 
        and IsNull(t1.Quantity,-1) != IsNull(t2.Quantity,-1) 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Change
FROM TABLE1 as t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 as t2 ON t1.RECORDSEQ = t2.RECORDSEQ + 1
)
SELECT 'ABCD' + CAST(122 + RANK() 
    OVER(PARTITION BY Change ORDER BY RECORDSEQ) as VARCHAR) as Autonumber
    , ProductSKU, Quantity
FROM Change
ORDER BY RECORDSEQ;
GO
```

It returns exactly what you want:

```
Autonumber  ProductSKU  Quantity
ABCD123     1597        42
ABCD123     1600        42
ABCD124     1597        35
ABCD124     1600        35
ABCD125     1597        39
ABCD125     1600        39
```

Comment: Sorry if it does not fit, but that what my crystal ball showed. If question be more informative there would be precise answer.

Comment: Hi Slava, please find my comments in the edited part and do suggest a precise answer :)

Comment: I've changed the query. See if now it is what you want.

Comment: Awesome :) That's exactly what I wanted..Thanks a lot Slava :)

Comment: Hi Slava, I have updated my query: How can I include the logic in this without disturbing the structure?

Comment: It depends, which logic

Comment: The Autonumer logic based on productsku & quantity which you have given. I want it implemented in the CTE itself and avoid the select statement that comes after that. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. Just wrap the second query in another CTE. You can have as many CTEs as you want.

Comment: But the second query has reference to  the first CTE right? Can this be included in another CTE?